# Estimating the Distribution of the data

Tags: kernel-smoothing, distribution-identification

I wanted to know the distribution of some discrete points and they don't follow any particular distribution according to the graphical and other methods. So, I thought of applying non-parametric method, KDE and obtained the KDE plot. Now I have 2 doubts:

1. How do I interpret that KDE plot so that I can proceed with estimating the parameters
2. Is there any other way, using which I can estimate the parameters for this?

These are the data-points:

```
data = [6,10,3,2,16,1,17,11,4,5]
```

Please let me know, even you have slightest idea regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Mathematica provides the function [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html).

FindDistribution[data] returns

```
DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 17}]
```

This implies a *discrete* uniform probability distribution over the integer values between 1 and 17, inclusive.

For a *continuous* distribution, one may assume that a uniform distribution of, say, between [0,18] could also be used.